# Interrupt after SYSCALL

Tags: assembly, x86-64, system-calls, interrupt

[The SYSCALL instruction does not save the stack pointer (RSP).](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/syscall)

Now consider instruction

```
mov rsp, -999
syscall
<interrupt>
```

Since `syscall` entered ring 0, interrupt would use stack from `rsp`, which would mess up kernel. Operating system can't do anything since it's not even ready to do anything.

Document also mentioned `SSP` which looks most likely to solve this, but I don't understand the relationship between `RSP`.

Comment: That's why interrupt masking exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's why `syscall` masks RFLAGS with the IA32_FMASK MSR, so in normal OSes where this would be a problem, it can be avoided by disabling interrupts.  (But `IF=0` doesn't stop an NMI; the TSS can provide an alternate stack for that<sup>1</sup>.)

This necessity for being able to mask interrupts until the kernel has set up SS:RSP was pointed out by Linux kernel devs when AMD64 was first proposed on paper, leading to the current design:

- http://web.archive.org/web/20160303170152/http://www.x86-64.org/pipermail/discuss/2000-October/001019.html spec change: adding the EFLAGS masking and saving the old RFLAGS in R11 in `syscall`/`sysret`
- http://web.archive.org/web/20160729112540/http://www.x86-64.org/pipermail/discuss/2000-October/001009.html spec addition: SwapGS to give the kernel a way to access per-task data without modifying any registers, so it can still preserve user-space's state (after `syscall` writes RCX and R11.)

Why not make `syscall` more complicated and also switch to a kernel stack for you, so there's a valid kernel stack once it completes?

- You'd need to store the old user-space stack pointer somewhere. (Or like `sysenter` does, make user-space stash it somewhere the kernel can find.)  I guess it could get pushed onto this new kernel stack if `syscall` did that, but then `syscall` accesses memory.  (Microcode can use temporary registers which aren't architecturally visible.)  But it could be a non-canonical address, could page-fault if the kernel wants to use pageable memory (or on a bad address), or could just be slow.
- With `swapgs`, it's up to the kernel how / where it wants to store per-task information.  A kernel just has to update one thing on context switches (the kernel GS base), not also an MSR with a kernel-stack pointer.
- One big microcoded instruction adds more corner cases for the microcode (including the possibility of faulting on a bad kernel RSP).  Also it's probably worse for performance.  (For Intel at least, `syscall` is an execution barrier: later instructions can't start out-of-order execing until after it's fully finished.)

  Keeping the system-call instruction lighter weight (e.g. *not* touching memory) was the design motivation for Intel's `sysenter` and AMD's `syscall` as faster alternatives to `int 0x80` or whatever.

---

Footnote 1: Nate Eldredge checked the manuals, and there's a separate mechanism that makes NMI handling possible with a fixed stack address, not easily allowing nesting:

> It seems that x86-64 added a special interrupt stack switching mechanism - they repurposed the TSS to hold pointers to up to 7 designated stack areas, and each IDT entry has a field to optionally select one of those stacks to switch to. It's not too useful for much besides NMI, since for instance you can't easily nest such interrupts, but it does solve this problem.

Comment: So if stack is anyway usually necessary(unless syscall is so small, which is unlikely), they should have did same to `RSP` like `RIP` do? How much time usually do the stack preparation and returning take if it's done by software with interrupt disabling?

Comment: @l4m2: The current design lets the kernel set RSP with normal loads (after `swapgs`), which are handled efficiently by the CPU.  It means the kernel can keep pointers to all the per-task info it needs in memory somewhere of its own choosing, without needing to reprogram *any* MSRs on context switches.  Or at most the kernel GS base via that MSR.  Also, doing more work inside one big microcoded instruction is often less good for performance, and means more corner cases for that one instruction.

Comment: I was wondering about the NMI thing also, so I looked it up.  It seems that x86-64 added a special interrupt stack switching mechanism - they repurposed the TSS to hold pointers to up to 7 designated stack areas, and each IDT entry has a field to optionally select one of those stacks to switch to.  It's not too useful for much besides NMI, since for instance you can't easily nest such interrupts, but it does solve this problem.

Comment: @NateEldredge That means some OS can make all interrupt don't use kernel stack, and it's therefore possible to have no kernel stack?

Comment: @l4m2: I'm not quite sure how you'd design that.  On Linux you have a kernel stack per process, to be used while executing system calls on behalf of the process.  Since it's part of the process's context, it means you can schedule out a process while it's in the kernel and then let it come back at the same spot.  If you don't have that, then what stack are system calls going to use instead?  It can't be the user's stack, you can't ever trust that.

Comment: @l4m2: Also, not being able to nest interrupts seems like a problem.  It means you can't safely enable interrupts within any interrupt handler.  So either you're going to have really long interrupt latency, or you have your interrupt handlers be very small and just enqueue work to be done later - but how does that later work get done, and what stack is *it* going to use?

Comment: @NateEldredge So each entry of TSS only support one interrupt, I thought it flag something. It's possible to use no stack in kernel, though maybe no modern OS do this

Comment: @l4m2: The hardware would allow you to use the same entry for multiple interrupts, there's no checking for it.  But then you'll have to ensure that none of those interrupts arrive while any one of them is being handled, and the simplest way to do that would be for the handler not to enable interrupts at all.  Or, do something tricky like having the handler modify the pointer in the TSS before enabling interrupts.

Comment: Does `syscall` use most of time disabling and enabling interrupt? Or is interrupt switch actually quite fast?

Comment: @l4m2: Linux configures `IA32_FMASK` so `syscall` disables interrupts.  The kernel entry point re-enables them after loading a kernel stack pointer.  Presumably the way Linux sets up the TSS doesn't cause a stack switch if an interrupt happens in kernel space, so there would be a window of unsafety if it did otherwise.  `sti` is slowish compared to instructions like `imul`, but cheaper than `syscall` itself.  (At least on the old CPUs where https://agner.org/optimize/ tested it: 16-17 uops on K8/K10 (early AMD64), with 27 cycle throughput.  17 uops on Pentium M).  IDK about now.

Comment: `cli` on those early AMD CPUs is only 8-9 uops, with 5 cycle throughput.  So that part of `syscall` isn't what makes it expensive.

Comment: Apparently (at least in the early 2000s when the AMD64 design was being discussed on x86-64.org mailing lists), Microsoft wanted interrupts enabled at the kernel's syscall entry point.  Maybe they have a per-core interrupt stack that their TSS uses even for interrupts that happen in kernel mode.  But as Nate said, that wouldn't work with nested interrupts.

Comment: I tried ` mov eax, 986534
 mov r15d, 100000000
a: syscall
 dec r15d
 jnz a` and get 27,207,080,153      cycles    20,512,852,460      instructions   . I'm currently without a raw computer to test real empty `syscall` or pure `sti/cli`

Comment: Under Linux?  Not sure how early it checks for `-ENOSYS`, but it might be changing page tables (for KPTI) and maybe doing IBRS Spectre mitigation before returning. (The later `syscall`s will be using the RAX return value from the last `syscall`, but `-ENOSYS` isn't a valid system call number so it's fine.) 272 cycles round trip for syscall/sysret is pretty good if that includes Spectre mitigation and so on. (Presumably on a modern Intel CPU?) Note that you can test `cli`/`sti` in user-space under Linux with `iopl()` to set your IO privilege level to 0, but be careful not to exit without `sti`.